# Converting Linq query expression to dot notation

Tags: c#, linq

I am just starting to learn LINQ. I wrote the following linq expression to get numbers in a list that are repeated 3 times.

```
 var query = from i in tempList
             where tempList.Count(num => num == i) == 3
             select i;
```

I want to know how to convert this to dot notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var query = tempList
            .GroupBy(i => i)
            .Where(g => g.Count() == 3)
            .Select(g => g.Key);
```

For example:

```
var tempList = new List<Int32>(){
    1,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9
};
IEnumerable<int> result = tempList
 .GroupBy(i => i)
 .Where(g => g.Count() == 3)
 .Select(g => g.Key); 

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",result));
```

Result: 3,7

Answer (score 1):

A *literal* conversion is as follows:

```
var query = tempList.Where(i => tempList.Count(num => num == i) == 3);
```

As Tim already mentioned, you could also achieve this using a GroupBy:

```
var query = tempList.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 3).Select(g => g.Key);
```

Note that the `GroupBy` version only returns *one* copy of each number, unlike your code that returns three copies of each number. Though I suspect you would prefer to get only one copy of each number.

Comment: Thats right I was using HashSet to get distinct elements after the query

Comment: @kr13: Why not just call `Distinct()`?

Comment: Hmm I think I read somewhere that using HashSet was more efficient

Comment: @kr13: If performance is an issue then you shouldn't be using a horribly inefficient algorithm in the first place.

Comment: Performance isnt an issue since Im only learning. But I do try to implement some of the things I read on these forums.

Comment: @kr13: I actually doubt that using HashSet is faster than Distinct.